# Toshiba Laptop A215-s7413 New Hard Drive cannot ruin recovery cds or windows installs

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, high-definition, toshiba-laptop

So I just ordered a new drive for my Toshiba laptop. I cannot for the life of me get windows or the restore disks to load they always just crash or stop halfway through. I have tired taking out a stick of ram different hard drives. Formatting the drive etc and etc. I don't have any bios options to change the Hard Drive settings just which order to boot. I have spent more than 4-5 hours on this am I missing something.

Does Toshiba encrypt there HD so you can only use the original? Is my cd drive bad?

Comment: Go to the drive manufacturer's site and download their drive diagnostic.  Roughly 2% of brand new drives may fail in the first year, and partial failure rates are much higher.

Comment: Drive is fine ran all tests and they passed :(

Comment: Then the odds are pretty good that it's your CD.

Comment: tried new cd drive no luck

Comment: also just updated the bios to newer version to see what would happend

Comment: There are just a finite number of possibilities.  i.e. did you get a hew HD because the old one failed?  In that case, maybe it's really the disk controller.  Did you verify the settings for the drive (if there are any under your control)?  Does it crash at a consistent point in the load, i.e. just after the reboot into Windows perhaps?  Did you try completely different RAM?  Did you try a different CD (not drive but disk)?  The fact that you're getting -some- files loaded would indicate that it can't be a drive-encryption issue, though Toshiba does have a password "gotcha" on original drives.

Comment: BTW, what version of Windows are you trying to install?

Comment: Yes I tried all that I got the original ram to try that out yea its either fails in installation or the windows install works then when it boots it fails. I have tried vista,7,8 windows version and original restore cds. After doing the bios update it got further than it ever did and but still ends up erroring out

Comment: Have you run the Toshiba diagnostics?  I can't help wondering if you have some damage on either graphics or drive controller.  Also, I'd suggest you see if you can load XP, if possible.

Comment: After trying everything I tried cloning another toshiba hd and that worked it booted up os. But It wont take drivers and even when I go to run a windows install or restore the same issue still happens freezes half way through the process

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Windows Install USB you can get the app here:

http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe

Comment: I tried that already and still no luck:( still shows missing windows files everytime

Comment: Tried new cd drive and usb drive still no luck